# How to change pull-down menu options based on checkbox setting?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following menu options defined:-

```
    <label><strong>Release #1:</strong></label>
    <select id="selectedBaseRelease">
        <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3" selected >ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file4">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label><strong>Release #2:</strong></label>
    <select id="selectedNewRelease">
        <option value="/~releases/file1" selected >ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
    </select>
```

I would like to add the following checkbox:-

```
    <strong>Include T-builds:</strong> <input type="checkbox" id="include_Ts"/>
```

...and when include_Ts is checked, I would like the list of values for selectedBaseRelease and selectedNewRelease to change, e.g. to something like...

```
    <label><strong>Release #1:</strong></label>
    <select id="selectedBaseRelease">
        <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file2a">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3" selected >ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3a">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file4">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file4a">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5a</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label><strong>Release #2:</strong></label>
    <select id="selectedNewRelease">
        <option value="/~releases/file1" selected >ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file1a">ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file2a">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
        <option value="/~releases/file3a">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option>
    </select>
```

How does one define an if-then condition to activate the alternate select id choices when include_Ts is checked?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to accomplish this using only CSS and no JavaScript. Live demo below.

A few things allow this to happen:

- We're giving the values you'd like hidden by default a class (`<option class="tbuild"...`)
- In the CSS, we're hiding elements with that class by default (`.tbuild { display: none; }`)
- In the CSS, we're also looking to see if the `#include_Ts` checkbox was checked, and if it is, we display those `.tbuild` options.

  - Note that for this to occur, the hierarchy needs to remain more or less the same as this demo. The checkbox needs to be prior to the select menus, and not within its own parent element separate from the `select` elements.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```css
.tbuild {
  display: none;
}

#include_Ts:checked~select .tbuild {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<strong>Include T-builds:</strong> <input type="checkbox" id="include_Ts" />

<br><br>

<label><strong>Release #1:</strong></label>
<select id="selectedBaseRelease">
  <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3" selected>ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file4">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file4a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5a</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label><strong>Release #2:</strong></label>
<select id="selectedNewRelease">
  <option value="/~releases/file1" selected>ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file1a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One caveat to note: If you check the checkbox, choose a T-build option and uncheck the checkbox, that selection will remain chosen. If this is an issue, JS would be needed to fix that.